# In CSS: how to specify the font you want as being BOTH monospace and sans-serif?

Tags: css, fonts, monospace

I'd like to tell the browser to use a font that is both monospace and sans-serif (usually the default monospace font has serifs, and the default sans-serif font isnt monospaced). Is there any way to specify this in CSS other than to provide a list of fonts I know to fit my criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS's [`font-family`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) doesn't allow specifying more than one generic font keyword in a single font family name, so you'll either have to go with `monospace` or `sans-serif`.

Comment: thanks... i guess this is the most correct answer - it's a shame that you cant generically choose a font that is monospaced and has no serifs

Comment: It's more of a "how" would a browser do that? A font creator could probably embed meta data, but that'd make all fonts before it have the same issue. Cool idea, but as fonts are created now it'd be impossible.

Comment: @Oscar: I don't think the existing labels like `serif` are implemented by scanning the metadata of all fonts on the system (which would still leave a problem how to choose the best of the matching ones).  There is simply a small table of *hand-picked* mappings, e.g. `monospace → Courier New` (chosen by browser & OS developers, and usually user-configurable).  This could be easily extended to have 2 separate mappings for `monospace serif` and `monospace sans-serif`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't say what type of family of font you want. CSS doesn't know if a font has serifs or not.

However, you can just look on here:
http://code.google.com/webfonts

And use one of those fonts and it'll work across all browsers.

Comment: thanks for the link to google webfonts, seems like a very good way to make sure your fonts are always available (if you trust this website to be around...). though i guess you could download it and host it yourself as well